# retrieving the alt text for a control in the javascript?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a image button placed for each row of a datagrid? using item template

I am just adding the alt text for each image at the datarowbound event?

the problem is it possible to retrieve the alt text for the images at the mouse over so that I could just display the alt text in the message box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want text to appear in the tool tip when the mouse cursor is hovering over the image, use the `title` attribute instead.

Comment: but is it possible to retreive the title for that image (which is an item template inaq javascript